# How to extract specific fields from json object and store it in a string in node.js

Tags: node.js, json, azure

So I am working with Azure APIs, and receive a response in a JSON Object.
I want to extract the `"text"` key and store the value in a string.
For this example, the result should be,
 `Hello World!`

This is the output right now.

```
{
 "language": "en",
 "textAngle": 0.02617993877991553,
 "orientation": "Up",
 "regions": [
  {
   "boundingBox": "169,81,846,138",
   "lines": [
    {
     "boundingBox": "169,81,846,138",
     "words": [
      {
       "boundingBox": "169,81,348,126",
       "text": "Hello"
      },
      {
       "boundingBox": "570,92,445,127",
       "text": "World!"
      }
     ]
    }
   ]
  }
 ]
}
```

How do I extract only the texts in node js?
Thankyou in advance

Comment: Is it always going to be the path regions.lines.words or does the path need to be dynamic as well?

Comment: Thankyou for commenting. It will always be regions.lines.words yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So i figured it out. Here is what i did.
You gotta use nested loops to get it.

```
    for(let j=0; j<lines.length; j++){
        let words=data.regions[0].lines[j].words;
        for( let i=0; i<words.length; i++){
            final_string += words[i].text + " ";
        }
        line_string = final_string;
    }
console.log(line_string);
```